# How can I get jQuery UI’s Draggable and Sortable functions to work on the Android browser?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-ui, touch

I have a question that is pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870432/how-can-i-get-jquery-uis-draggable-and-sortable-functions-to-work-on-the-iphone) one.

Is it possible to make the jQuery UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and sortable interaction work on in the Android browser?

Comment: have u checked the jquery mobile ? its made especially for mobile phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQTouch](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http://www.jqtouch.com/&ei=_J3uT4-ICpHLrQf80MW9DQ&usg=AFQjCNEI--nqPC2jrRNA2tnHq78zaCHtFQ&sig2=o_YsAGEHsb9KouGO2M1zaw). They have handled various kinds of gestures/events for touch phones.