# What is going on with jQuery UI Sortable on a touch screen device?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, touch, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable).

I am developing a mobile only website, so I looked around how to map touch events to mouse events for this to work, and ended up using some [code by Oleg Slobodskoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745098/jquery-ui-sortable-doesnt-work-on-touch-devices-based-on-android-or-ios/6795028#6795028).

This appeared to work nicely. However, on a mobile device (I am using an iPhone to test, but it also happens on the iPhone simulator), when you attempt to shift a second item (i.e. the next item to sort after you have sorted one already), its initial position is offset either side by about the width of the element.

[image: Example]

<sup>When I attempt the second time to drag one of these pink boxes, instead of appearing underneath my finger and shifting with it, it starts about the width of a box away, to the left or right, and then *jumps* under my finger.</sup>

I've set up an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhK67/). Hit the *attach* button to add jQuery Sortable to the list items.

I have tried many things, including playing with the `change` event and attempting to realign it back, but I couldn't get it to reliably work.

How can I stop this problem?

Comment: I found this poking around the web http://forum.jquery.com/topic/are-you-planning-any-fix-to-make-jquery-ui-sortable-work-on-touch-devices-at-least-on-mobile-safari-and-android-browser

Comment: @rwilliams Thanks, I did find that, however it is not going to be released for a while.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Super simple solution for this one. I wish I could say it was super simple to find, but no... it took a while.

To clarify the symptom, it's that the initially-dragged element is always the one that is dragged on subsequent drags.  If you start out dragging `b`, on subsequent drags `b` is the one that always moved.  Likewise for `a` and `c`.

This made me question if perhaps the event was being "recycled."  I confirmed that the `pageX` and `pageY` values were correct on the `touchstart` (and `touchmove`) event, but the values getting to `_mouseDown` in Sortable were wrong.  So, I went to `jquery.ui.mouse.js` and looked at `_mouseDown` there.  I confirmed that the proper values were coming through, but that the handler was exiting at this line at the top of the method:

```
// don't let more than one widget handle mouseStart
if( mouseHandled ) { return };
```

So, I started looking at `mouseHandled`.  There was only one line where this was reset back to `false` - the following listener at the top:

```
$( document ).mouseup( function( e ) {
    mouseHandled = false;
});
```

I realized I must be close.  I looked back at the `_touchEnd` method in the compatibility add-in you're using:

```
_touchEnd: function(event) {
   this.element.unbind("touchmove." + this.widgetName).unbind("touchend." + this.widgetName);
   this._mouseUp(event);
},
```

Note that `_mouseUp` is only called on the widget itself -- not the `document`!  Thus, clearly `mouseHandled` was never being reset.  So, I added a `document` dispatch line to `_touchEnd`:

```
_touchEnd: function(event) {
   this.element.unbind("touchmove." + this.widgetName).unbind("touchend." + this.widgetName);
   this._mouseUp(event);
   $(document).trigger('mouseup', event);
},
```

And *presto*, everything worked correctly.

**So, in summary, this one line is the magic one:**

```
$(document).trigger('mouseup', event);
```

Working forked fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NxKfa/) [[direct link for iOS viewing](http://jsfiddle.net/NxKfa/embedded/result/)].

---

Note: I also changed this line:

```
/ iPad | iPhone /.test(navigator.userAgent) && (function($) {
```

To:

```
/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && (function($) {
```

Because it didn't work properly with spaces, and you should include support for the iPod touch.

Comment: @alex: Happy to help.  I hope it's helpful to the Sortable-using community!  Plus, maybe it will also help those debugging similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more important thing.
Everything works great, but only as long as we don't scroll the page down.
The problem is that Y touch position is relative to window top, not the document.
I've fixed this changing the line:

```
event.pageY = target.clientY;
```

Into this:

```
event.pageY = target.clientY + $(window).scrollTop();
```