# jQuery Sortable not working in Android mobile

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted to implement drag and drop functionality in my app and so I used the jQuery sortable implementation given at: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/.

I have sucessfully implemented it and it's working fine in my laptop in Google chrome but it is not working in my Android 2.3 Gingerbread mobile. What's Wrong?

What should I do to have a drag and drop functionality work in my mobile. I have already tried the new HTML5 implementation and that too is not working.

Comment: I doubt the stock browser in gingerbread can handle all HTML5 functionnalities. You can test it here : http://html5test.com/index.html Moreover, i'm not sure that jQueryUI sortable uses touch events. Please see this answer for a possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745098/jquery-ui-sortable-doesnt-work-on-touch-devices-based-on-android-or-ios

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). I've tested it on iOS 5 and Android 2.3 and it works great on both.