# Modal button in sortable li tag not clickable on mobile devices

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable

I am making the mobile version of a php website that has a sortable list.
Inside the li tag there are three divs, the first and the second are clickable and should open a modal window.

```
<ul id='sortable'>
//...multiple li tags
<li class='ui-state-default row'>
    <div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-edit' onclick='modificaModale()'>
        <i class='fas fa-edit iconeScheda'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-elimina-esercizio' onclick='eliminaModale()'>
        <i class='fas fa-trash-alt iconeScheda'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-10 col-xs-10'>
        <b>Name of exercise</b>
    </div>
</li>
//...
</ul>
```

On a desktop browser everything works fine but on mobile devices the two divs are not clickable and the modal won't open.
If I remove the sortable the modal opens on mobile too.
My head tag looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script>

        function modificaModale(id) {
            //do stuff
        }

        function eliminaModale() {
            //do stuff
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                axis: 'y',
                type: 'li',
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                    $.ajax({
                        data: data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'some url'
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
```

and the style of those

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; cursor: grab;}
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }

.iconeScheda{
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

one of my modal is like this (the other is pretty much the same)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-elimina-esercizio" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="background: none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="eliminaScheda.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="id" id="idElimina" style="display:none"/>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Elimina</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Sei sicuro di voler eliminare <span id="esercizioModale"></span>?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Conferma"/>
                    <input type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Annulla"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without the "sortable" id, the modals open normally.
Here pictures of the web:
[desktop version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnbCZ.jpg)
and the mobile version:
[mobile version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkWyP.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can try out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726701/jquery-sortable-not-working-in-android-mobile if sortable not working in mobile

Comment: Thanks @NiravJoshi but sortable is working, it is modal buttons inside the sortable tag that are not working on mobile devices

Comment: Thanks to your codepen I realized that it wasn't working due to the <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

Comment: ok then you can accept answer :)

Comment: Sorry @niravjoshi but it is not the right answer, when you open your codepen on a smartphone it is not sortable anymore

Answer (score 0):

As I checked code in codepen 
[codepen.io/nickjackson139/pen/PoorWOG](http://codepen.io/nickjackson139/pen/PoorWOG) in mobile view it is opening model.

```js
function modificaModale(id) {
  //do stuff
}

function eliminaModale() {
  //do stuff
}

$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    type: 'li',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'some url'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: grab;
}

#sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}

.iconeScheda {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<ul id='sortable'>

  <li class='ui-state-default row'>
    <div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-edit' onclick='modificaModale()'>
      <i class='fas fa-edit iconeScheda'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-elimina-esercizio' onclick='eliminaModale()'>
      <i class='fas fa-trash-alt iconeScheda'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-10 col-xs-10'>
      <b>Name of exercise</b>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-elimina-esercizio" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="background: none">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="eliminaScheda.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="id" id="idElimina" style="display:none" />
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>Elimina</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Sei sicuro di voler eliminare <span id="esercizioModale"></span>?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" value="Conferma" />
          <input type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Annulla" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```